# HTML5 semantics support for all browsers that need it

Tags: html, cross-browser, semantics

So there's [HTMLshiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) and we're told to use it with IE9-, but [older versions of other browsers don't fully support those tags](http://caniuse.com/#html5semantic).

What's the combined conditional statement to use for them all ?

Or maybe HTMLshiv only works for IE, if so, how to bring support to other browsers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTMLshiv only makes your elements style-able via CSS. Most (all?) non IE browser will let you style unknown tags, but older IE needs a little help from the shiv, to be able to style these tags. That is really the only thing that the shiv does. It DOES NOT "bring support" to any browser.

John Resig explains it pretty well here: http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/

Comment: The shiv does a little more than that. It changes the structure of the DOM. While the most useful consequence of that is that the contents become styleable, it will also affect the addressability and manipulation of the element in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the added info Alohci.